# Linux + Apache to detect the Connection Counts of each Vhosts?

Tags: linux, apache, connection, vhosts

With RHEL and Apache (httpd), is there a way to:

- Detect which v.host (domain) is gaining how many incoming connections?

Because in this few days, i got a lot of incoming connections on the Server being acknowledged by using:

- ps aux | grep httpd -c
  734

That means i have `734` incoming connections currently being handled by Apache but the problem is i have (lets say) 10 Vhosts (domains).

- So which Domain is getting the high loads?

Any sharp solutions please.

Answer (score -1):

Say you have a file like /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-example.com

You may see lines like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com 
    DocumentRoot /www/example.com
```

Further down, If you want, you can create logfiles for each VirtualHost by changing lines

```
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Too:

```
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example_com.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example_com.access.log combined
```

Otherwise, if you don't want to create logfiles for each VirtualHost, then you can create your own custom log format http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats

For example:

```
    LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log common
```

When you have decided how you want to log, then you can write all kinds of scripts to examine or compare your logs. It would be far easier if you are using separate logfiles for each virtualhost, because you may try this.

```
 wc -l /var/log/apache2/*access.log
```

Comment: the question is not logging per virtualhost, but active connection counts per virtualhost